# Pass A Generic Codable Type as Parameter to a Method for Saving to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm, codable

I am trying to create a generic method for decoding some JSON data. I need to cast the JSON data into Objects for later saving in Realm.

For example: Getting the makes, models, colors, and body types of vehicles.

In each of my JSON calls to the results are formatted exactly the same (See my structs at the end of the question). For brevity, I am only showing you Makes and Models, but Colors and Body Types are exactly the same, just with the name changes.

I currently have four methods that I call where `Makes.self` is replaced with one of the other structs.

```
if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Makes.self, from: jsonData)) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //save data to realm
        self?.save(objects: results.data )
    }
}
```

Once I get my JSON Data, I would like to send my data to a generic method for processing.

So I could call something like :

```
process(jsonData, modelType: Makes.self)
process(jsonData, modelType: Models.self)
process(jsonData, modelType: Colors.self)
process(jsonData, modelType: Bodies.self)
```

I have tried variations on generic types but I can't seem to get it right.

```
func process<T:Codable>(_ jsonData: Data, modelType: T.Type = T.self) {

        if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(modelType.self, from: jsonData) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //save data to realm
                self?.save(objects:results.data)
            }
        }
}
```

**How can I pass a Decodable Protocol type as a generic?**

**MAKES**

```
import RealmSwift

struct Makes: Codable {
    let result: String
    let data: [Make]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case result = "Result"
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

class Make: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var key: String
    @objc dynamic var value: String
    @objc dynamic var shortCode: String
    @objc dynamic var active: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key = "Key"
        case value = "Value"
        case shortCode = "ShortCode"
        case active = "Active"
    }
}
```

**MODELS**

```
import RealmSwift

struct Makes: Codable {
    let result: String
    let data: [Make]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case result = "Result"
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

class Make: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var key: String
    @objc dynamic var value: String
    @objc dynamic var shortCode: String
    @objc dynamic var active: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key = "Key"
        case value = "Value"
        case shortCode = "ShortCode"
        case active = "Active"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect any `Codable` type to have a `data` property? `results.data` cannot work... You need to make `T` a subclass of `Object` to be able to save it to `Realm` and also `Decodable` to be able to pass it to the `decode` method.

```
func process<T:Object>(_ jsonData: Data, modelType: T.Type) where T:Decodable {
    if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(modelType.self, from: jsonData) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //save data to realm
            self?.save(objects:results)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `results.data` is the property that contains the object I want to save once it has been decoded.  In your example, the generic parameter of `Decodable` can not be used in a function signature. Among two other errors with the `modelType.self`

Comment: @user-44651 check my updated answer, it compiles fine now. As I've already said, `Codable` doesn't contain a `data` property, so you cannot use that. You need to pass the actual type that you want to decode into the function. If all of your encoded `Object` subclasses are part of a common root object in the JSON, make that root object generic too.